# How do I Include ampersand (&) in CODEOWNERS github file

Tags: git, github, filepath, gitignore

The path of the directory is like:

`helpers resources/apples & oranges/testing files/`

I've tried surrounding the entire path in quotes.

I've tried `helpers\ resources/apples\ \&\ oranges/testing\ files`.

I've tried url encoding the path.

Escaping the spaces in other paths is working fine and the CODEOWNERS file works properly if I remove the path with the `&`.

Comment: How did you do the quotes? It ought to work I think, in any case use escape on spaces & replace `&` with `*` is it going to work then? But again quotes should've worked!

Comment: I suspect that if you provide a [mcve] people will be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Try just putting quotes around `apples & oranges`, like this:

```
helpers resources/"apples & oranges"/testing files/
```

Comment: If quotes work, you probably have to use straight quotes `"apples & oranges"` instead of smart quotes `“apples & oranges”`. When writing code, make sure to turn off your operating system’s or text editor’s Smart Quotes feature. On macOS you can usually do this by right-clicking the text area and looking in the Substitutions sub-menu.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Thanks for letting me know about that.  I have updated my answer to show straight quotes.

Answer (score 1):

So quotes didn't seem to work anywhere in the CODEOWNERS file. Our work around was to use an asterisk and this was good enough for our use case.

`helpers\ resources/apples\ *\ oranges/testing\ files`